# App Crashing - probably because of SqlDataAccess

Tags: c++, sqlite, blackberry-10

I am using Blackberry Cascades.

I am trying to access my database to insert/edit etc. my database but the app crashes the moment I try to call on the query function *favourite()*.

The app crashes and nothing gets logged in the console so I am not sure what exactly is causing it.

I have also declared in the header: **SqlDataAccess * sda**

```
#include "dbHelper.h"
#include <bb/data/SqlDataAccess>
#include <bb/data/DataAccessError>

#include <QtSql/QtSql>
#include <QDebug>

dbHelper::dbHelper()
{
    initDatabase();
    SqlDataAccess sda (mdbFilewithPath);
    // or should I use: this-> sda = new SqlDataAccess();
}

void dbHelper::initDatabase(){
    //Copy database to Data folder ... pretty sure this part of the code works.
    mdbFilewithPath =  QDir::homePath() + "/data.db";
}

void dbHelper::executeQuery (const QString query){

    this->sda->execute(query);
    if (this->sda->hasError()){
        DataAccessError err = this->sda->error();
        qWarning() << "SQL Error: " << err.errorType() <<err.errorMessage();
    }

}

void dbHelper::favourite(const QString &rule_id)
{

    QVariantMap rule;
    rule["id"] = rule_id;
    QString query ="INSERT INTO user (rule_id, isFavourite) VALUES (" + rule_id + ", 1)";
    executeQuery(query);
}
```

I am not sure what is causing it? Would appreciate any help thanks!

Comment: When an application you wrote crashes, your first instinct should be to run the program in a debugger. This will help you locate the place where the crash happens, as well as letting you examine values of variables and the call stack. Also, all phone development kits that I've tried (which doesn't include the BB devkit) have emulators where you can easily debug the applications. It might also be possible to debug remotely from the actual hardware.

Comment: I see, I will try that now first thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible to debug on phone or on Simulator, various people favour one or the other.  It is also possible to run the debug version and watch the qDebug() output, so even if the debugging doesn't work, the console output should be visible. I recommend adding some more debugging lines to determine where the app is failing. That said, there is a bit of a learning curve involved in this for BB10, so do take it slowly and practise on the sample apps.  Good luck

Comment: I second what Peter said, and add that while you indicated you declare sda as a pointer to SqlDataAccess, you don't indicate how sda is initialized. Dereferencing a null pointer will cause an abort.

Comment: // or should I use: this-> sda = new SqlDataAccess();
Yes, you should